# Android - Intent within ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-intent

I am not able to create an intent in my Listview. It gives an error "unable to instantiate
activity ComponentInfo" and caused by Classcastexception. here's the snippet -

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Vol.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }});
```

this is the portion of the code creating trouble -

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Vol.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

I cant understand why its giving ClassCastException. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: pls change view.getContext() to ClassName.this

Comment: I did that. Still doesnt work. Any more suggestions? I'd really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give event like this

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
         if(position==0){
             Intent i = new Intent(this, abc.class);
             startActivity(i);

        } else if(position==1){
             Intent i = new Intent(this, xyz.class);
             startActivity(i);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(yourActivity.this, Vol.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

Comment: still doesn't work. And by yourActivity do you mean the class which contains this code?

Comment: the class extends ListActivity, as this activity is a ListView.

Comment: its also ok.put your class name instead of yourActivity

Comment: yes. I have declared the Vol activity in the manifest. Why is it giving ClassCastException?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing it like this,

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Vol.class);
view.getContext().startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }});
```

This might be because of context problem. If

```
 view.getContext().startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

is not working, try passing different contexts for `startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);`.

Comment: didnt work. And what do you mean by "try passing different contexts for startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);" ?

Comment: Instead of passing view.getContext(), try passing your parent's context or application context. I am not sure.

Comment: i am sorry but I cant understand what you mean by that. if you could tell me exactly.. thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me on which line exactly you are getting this error

Comment: the code runs fine without the following. I can see the listview. I even tried to display toast messages on that listview and it worked. Now I want to start a new intent when I select anything on the list.

Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Vol.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

?

and don't forget to register your activity within the AndroidManifest.xml in the  tag..

like :

```
<activity: android:name=".ExampleActivity" android:label="My ExampleActivity!" />
```